# How can I modify all nodes in a DocumentFragment?

Tags: javascript, dom, range, selection

I am getting a DocumentFragment from a Range, which is from a Selection:

`var foo = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents()`

1. How can I iteratively modify all nodes in the DocumentFragment?
2. How can I re-insert this DocumentFragment to overwrite the original Selection?

https://codepen.io/MichaelArnoldOwens/pen/wvMwzLY

Answer (score 1):

```
// i just used Selection to get a DocumenetFragment, but this can be applied to any DocumentFragment
var contents = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).extractContents()
// I generate a NodeList with querySelectorAll() and pass it the wildcard selector to get all the nodes
let list = contents.querySelectorAll('*')
// I instantiate a new DocumentFragment
let newFrag = new DocumentFragment()
// I iterate through the node list and make any modifications I want to each node before appending it to the new DocumentFragment
for (let i of list) {
  i.style.color = 'red'
  newFrag.appendChild(i)
}
// you can now append your new DocumentFragment to the DOM
...
```